# Using wildcards in ruby/watir

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm controlling an IE page using watir.

I have this command:-

```
browser.frame(:id,"ultraposuidialoghtm0").div(:class," content").button(:id,"ok").click
```

However the `ultraposuidialoghtm0` part increments, so I get `ultraposuidialoghtm1` etc.

How do I label my id as `ultraposuidialoghtm*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it supports regular expressions in [method calls](https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/Finding-Page-Elements#regular-expressions). Maybe it's worth trying something like:

```
browser
  .frame(:id, /ultraposuidialoghtm[0-9]*/)
  .div(:class," content")
  .button(:id, "ok")
  .click
```

I can't really test it at the moment, but it might be wort checking!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If id values are being used in accordance with the html spec, then they are unique within a page or frame.  In that case you can use

```
browser
  .frame(:id, /ultraposuidialoghtm[0-9]*/)
  .button(:id, "ok").click
```

Using regular expressions can be slow however, so if the number and order of frames on the page is known, or if the frame is contained by some other easy to find container element, then you might want to locate by index, or just the first frame inside the container.

```
browser.div(:class => 'frame holder').frame.button(:id => 'ok').click
```